# Linux print file names based on pattern

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have requirement where I need to list files from directory which has unique pattern and in case of repeat choose the one which is updated most recently to avoid duplicate records.

Files:

```
    File Name                                               Update Time
    Test-11121202025-20201006-111506-1601997306.txt         Oct 25, 2020
    Test-11121202025-20201006-111506-1801997306.txt         Oct 30, 2020
    Test-77722202025-20201006-111506-1601997306.txt         Oct 25, 2020
```

Desired Output in this case:

```
Test-01121202025-20201006-111506-1801997306.txt
Test-77722202025-20201006-111506-1601997306.txt
```

Explanation : First and second file is same as per my use case since Test-11121 (Initial 10 char ) is same in initial two files however second one in updated most recently so I will discard the first one.
in addition to that since third file is unique as there is only one entry  with pattern (Test-77722) so i will also consider this is in output.

I tried below command but that's not helping. I guess I can achieve using shell Script but would like to refrain from doing this for this small use case

```
 ls -lt| awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"}{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You say *"since Test-11121 (Initial 10 char ) is same in initial two files"* But one is `Test-11121` and the other is `Test-01121`. Did you mean to say they are the same because every other character besides the initial 10 are the same or is your example bad?

Comment: @JNevill Sorry my bad. Corrected. Thanks for highlighting

Comment: not sure why there is down vote? any suggestion  to improve my question

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for link. I will check and try some alternative

Comment: You don't really need to "parse" the output here - with time based sorting all you need is the filename.  The "parse" here is a red herring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink 0 2020-09-12 16:48 Test-11121202025-20201006-111506-1601997306.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink 0 2020-10-31 07:04 Test-11121202025-20201006-111506-1801997306.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink 0 2020-10-31 07:03 Test-77722202025-20201006-111506-1601997306.txt
```

And `awk` to the rescue:

```
$ ls -tr | awk '{a[substr($1,1,10)]=$0} END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}'
Test-77722202025-20201006-111506-1601997306.txt
Test-11121202025-20201006-111506-1801997306.txt
```

Edit: the way this works is we create an array, indexed by the first 10 characters of each filename, containing the whole filename.  As the files are sorted oldest to newest only the last one matching the first 10 characters will be in the array.  At the end we just iterate over the array and output all the most recent filenames.